# Navigating to a page in a custom event doesn't work properly

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When I navigate to a page using this event:

```
this.events.subscribe('liveTrackingEvent', (time, unit) => {
        console.log("event triggered");
        this.searchForm.controls['unitID'].setValue(this.unitSelected.unit.name);
        this.GetLiveData();
    });
```

everything gets called, also the function GetLiveData(). (I didn't post this function's code because it's irelevant)

However when I look at the page, not 1 element is updating. So this line:

```
this.searchForm.controls['unitID'].setValue(this.unitSelected.unit.name);
```

doesn't update the searchform control, however when I call this line of code from the page itself without the event getting triggered on another page, it works smoothly and updates the searchform control.

(It's like I'm on a separate thread for some reason), I'm putting this between brackets because it's just a thought.

So my question is: How do I force this page to update itself also when the event is triggered?

Thanks in advance and if you guys need more code just ask, but this is the most relevant code because everything is working just not when it gets called inside the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using page life cycle events instead of custom events from the ionic framework I managed to make this work and even have a cleaner code.
example:

1st page:

```
GoToLiveTracking(unitID){
    this.navCtrl.push(MapPage, {redirected: true, unitID: unitID});
}
```

2nd page:

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
    if(this.navParams.get('redirected')){
        let unit_id = this.navParams.get('unitID');
        this.unitSelected = this.completeService.GetUnitByID(unit_id);
        this.searchForm.controls['unitID'].setValue(this.unitSelected.unit.name);
        this.GetLiveData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could think of only 1 reason for this behavior. You are updating your form  outside of Angular Zone. That’s why the changes are not getting detected.

To fix the issue, wrapped the call of last 2 lines of event into “[this.ngZone.run(() => { ... })](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#ngzone)”.

e.g

```
    this.events.subscribe('liveTrackingEvent', (time, unit) => {
            console.log("event triggered");
            this.ngZone.run(()=>{            

       this.searchForm.controls['unitID'].setValue(this.unitSelected.unit.name);
            this.GetLiveData();
});
        });
```

Comment: Thx this also fixed the problem but I'm sticking to my solution.